# How to uppercase a unique identifier when exporting to CSV with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

When exporting a SQL dataset that contains a unique identifier in the first column, Powershell/.NET is transforming the GUID to lowercase.  This is to be used in a down stream system that is requiring the GUID's to be uppercased.  What is the cleanest way to get the GUID to export uppercased?

Here is the export portion that we are currently using:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $OuputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Is the name of the first column always the same?

Comment: Yes, the first column is always named "Item UUID".  Unfortunately, it has a space in it which is also required by the down stream system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe the data via `ForEach-Object` and modify the relevant property value before exporting:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] |ForEach-Object {
  $_.'Item UUID' = $_.'Item UUID'.ToString().ToUpper()
  $_
} |Export-Csv $OuputFile -NoTypeInformation
```